# example.com to https://www.example.com | Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, redirect, apache2, www

So I want to redirect `example.com` to `https://www.example.com`. I already have ssl with certbot but I want to change my redirect config in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.conf`.

Certbot already gives you a redirect from `example.com` to `https://example.com`.

this is my current apache config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About mod\_rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Yup this answers it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The [recommended configuration](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect) for simple redirects is to avoid rewrite rules and simply set up a Redirect directive:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    Redirect permanent "/" " https://www.example.com/" 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This sadly does not answer my question as rewrite engine is required and made use of by certbot.